# Why directive ng-init doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs

I want to initialize variable `test` on value from `formErrors.field1` but it doesn't work.

```
{{formErrors.field1}} // show content

<input ng-model="test" ng-init="test = formErrors.field1" /> // input field is empty

{{test}} // doesn't show content
```

I'm using Angular version angular-1.3.0-rc.1

Answer (score 0):

If the field value gets set after the page loads, maybe it could explain why you face this issue.

I use ng-init mostly to set values directly, not to copy the value of another scope variable.

Comment: It's set after click on submit button.

Comment: Ok, then I think this is why.
I believe you will have to implement something on the jsvascript side, to update $scope.test when you set formErrors.field1 value